# Blackberry RichTextField validation

Tags: blackberry

I have created a [`RichTextField`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/RichTextField.html) and I want to have it allow only integer values. How can I make that happen?

Comment: RichTextField is a read-only field. Why do you want to apply a filter on this.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
public class MyRichTextField extends RichTextField {

    public MyRichTextField() {
        super();
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        try {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(text);
            super.setText("" + x);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // the text is not a number
            super.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```